# Altering fontsize in equations globally

Tags: equations, align, fontsize

I am trying to typeset all formulas in an article using `\small` font.

If I use `\DeclareMathSizes{9}{8}{6}{4}`, then the size of in-line math in regular text is also changed. However, I want to redefine the font size only for multi-line equations wrapped in an `align` environment.

I also tried to redefine the align command in the following way:

```
\let\oldalign=\align
\renewcommand{\align}{\small\oldalign}
```

This results in some text paragraphs after `align` environments now being typeset in `\small` font, although well outside the `align` environment. Sorry, I don't have a minimal example right now. It might have to do with the `cls` template I'm using (`sig-alt-full`).

I tried adding a `\normalsize` as a fix, without success:

```
\let\oldalign=\align
\renewcommand{\align}{\small\oldalign\normalsize}
```

I then proceeded to defining my own `align` environment, as follows:

```
\newenvironment{myalign}
{% begin code
\begin{small}
\begin{align}
}
{% end code
\end{align}
\end{small} }
```

This one fails because, according to LaTeX, `\begin{small}` is ended by `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could normally use `\pretocmd\start@align` with `etoolbox` to apply something at the start of an `align`, but does not work in this case as the `\DeclareMathSizes` needs to be part of the preamble, not something that gets executed a the start of the `align` environment.

Comment: presumably, since you want all formulas to be set in a smaller size, it's also okay to have the equation numbers in the same small size.  but i thought it worth asking.  (there's a workaround for `amsmath` to keep the equation numbers the same size as the normal text since it does make a difference if only some displayed formulas are made smaller.  this may become a feature with the next overhaul of `amsmath`; it's on the list for consideration.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it's really a good idea. However the following seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\newenvironment{myalign}{\par\nobreak\small\noindent\align}{\endalign}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{myalign}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{myalign}
\lipsum[2]

\renewenvironment{myalign}{\par\nobreak\tiny\noindent\align}{\endalign}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{myalign}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{myalign}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The redefinition is just to show more clearly that it works (small size is not so different from normal size).

[image]

---

If you want to use the original `align` and `align*` environments, then the following trick will do

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\align{\par\nobreak\small\noindent}
\expandafter\preto\csname align*\endcsname{\par\nobreak\small\noindent}
```

Similar tricks can be used for the other alignment environments.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\align{\par\nobreak\small\noindent}
\expandafter\preto\csname align*\endcsname{\par\nobreak\small\noindent}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{align}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align*}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{align*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. Can I also redefine the original `align` environment? Then I can leave my document as is. The obvious approach (e.g. `\renewenvironment{align}{\par\nobreak\small\noindent\align}{\endalign}`) does not work.

Comment: Obviously, I can, by doing the following: `\let\oldalign=\align` followed by a
`\let\oldendalign=\endalign` followed by a 
`\renewenvironment{align}{\par\nobreak\scriptsize\noindent\oldalign}{\oldendalign}`. However, this does not affect `{align*}` environments. Why not?

Comment: @janschaf I've added the change you desired

Comment: No, actually that doesn't seem to work. No LaTeX error but also no change in font size in the resulting document (I replaced `\small` with `\footnotesize`).

Comment: @janschaf It works; you probably didn't put the code in the right place; I added a full example.