# Changing size for inline math and for math environments separately

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I am writing my thesis in the memoir class, and had to change the general font size for the document to 12pt. Because I use a lot of `align` environments with long formulas, I changed the size of these via

```
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{10}{8}{7}
```

to 10pt with even smaller (script)script sizes.

The problem is, that this not only changes the setup in explicit math environments, but also for expressions like `$a$` that are used inline in the text.

My question is therefore: Is it possible to access the sizes in math environments and for inline math separately? Since I practically only use the `align` environment, I thought about changing things there specifically, but I would prefer a solution that either

a) Changes explicitly only the settings in (all) math environments, but not inline, or

b) Changes the inline math size back, after it is set to 10pt with the command shown above.

Since the document is quite large, manually setting the size for every inline math command is sadly not practical.

Thank you in advance, audiophiel

**EDIT:** I adopted some techniques shown in [Altering fontsize in equations globally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82535/altering-fontsize-in-equations-globally), however I would still be thankful for a "cleaner" approach.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to change font size at all. This seems to be an editorial question more than anything else. Reedit the displayed math instead.

Comment: As someone who writes papers with a lot of math and (more important) reads papers with a lot of math I can only beg you not to shrink sizes to accommodate long expressions. Your readers will be thankful.

Comment: I was asked to increase the font size of the text to 12pt, but the whole document was set in the default of the memoir class (10pt). Personally, I don't like this large fonts, but I have to comply. The main problem is that by in creasing the size, allot of the formulas became to long, and inserting line breaks in that many formulas is a lot of work and the result looks bad.